# Jquery doesnt assign CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to assign a class to an a href tag if this his clicked, in other words, if one address is in the address bar, assign one class to this tag..

I have this styles in my css..

```
ul#menu li a {
padding: 10px 20px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
color: #465c71;
}

ul#menu li a.selected {
padding: 10px 20px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Where only change the font color..

And this jquery script in the Layout page of my mvc3 project..

I have this function..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      $("#menu li a").each(function () {
      var addr = $(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
      if (addr == pgurl)
          $(this).addClass("selected");
  })
 });
 </script>
```

Where pgurl is the bold value http://local.host:81/Home/**Services** (Sure, because i use and works in another jquery function)

And I have a a href link like this..

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Services", "Home")">@MvcWebRole1.Resources.Shared.Layout.Services</a></li>
```

And this above generates a link as this..

```
<a href="/Home/Services">Services</a>
```

Where i want to add a class to this tag if the first variable is the same of page that i am.. I i do through firebug or similar (add manually the class) works as expected..

Finally, two variables should have the bold value(Services), but doesnt add the class at the tag, i work with Visual Studio 2010 and i cant test this values, i cant put any breakpoint on it to view their values.. And as commented above, i have another similar function thats works perfectly with the tags of another list..

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var addr = $(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
```

The above assigns a `number` + 1 to `addr`. You then go on to test this number is equal to a string so unless your action is a number (not sure if it can be), then it will always fail.

Maybe you meant to get the substring from the link as well

```
 var addr = $(this).attr("href").substr($(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```